# How to change the resolution of a lattice through the Blender API?

Tags: lattice

I am creating a lattice through the Blender API and I want to change the resolution when I create it:

```
collection = bpy.context.collection

lattice = bpy.data.lattices.new("Lattice")
lattice_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Lattice", lattice)
lattice_ob.scale = (224, 352, 224)
lattice_ob.location = (112,176,112)
```

I am trying to change the resolution of my lattice by using:

```
lattice_ob.points_u = 10
lattice_ob.points_v = 10
lattice_ob.points_w = 10
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'points_u'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's the data part of the lattice.**

Just like vertices belong to a mesh, the resolution belongs to a lattice ID object, `bpy.data.lattices` which is the data part of the lattice object.

```
lattice_ob.data.points_u = 10
```

or as defined in question code

```
lattice.points_u = 10
```

Any property seen in the DATA part of the properties panel belongs to the data part of the object of its given type. In this case `bpy.types.Lattice` object being the data of `bpy.types.Object.type == 'LATTICE'`.
`